# Get all entries which column value starts with a string - doesn't work when column value contains links

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a column *text* where values can contain also links. I want to get all entries which have this column starting with a specific word. I've tried:

```
select * from my_table WHERE column_name LIKE 'word%';

SELECT * from my_table WHERE column_name  ~ '^word.*';
```

but doesn't work: even if I have values in that column which starts with *word* e.g.: 
`word: https://www.google.com/` the queries returns 0 results.

Comment: What do you mena by "doesn't work"? Post some example data.

Comment: added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how this shouldn't work:

```
db=# create table my_table (column_name text);
db=# =# insert into my_table values ('foo'), ('word'), ('bar'), ('word: https://www.google.com/');
db=# select * from my_table where column_name like 'word%';
 column_name
-------------
 word
 word: https://www.google.com/
(2 rows)

db=# select * from my_table where column_name ~ '^word.*';
 column_name
-------------
 word
 word: https://www.google.com/
(2 rows)
```

Comment: it works fine when it doesn't contain links; please insert values with links  `db=# insert into my_table values ('word: https://www.google.com/');`

Comment: @Paul, I've added your example. It works as expected. Are you sure there isn't a leading space (or other invisible character) before "word"?

Comment: stupid me.. inside _word_ there was an uppercase letter which I've omitted.